# New to Jetty- waiting for response data with continuations, ASYNCSTARTED exception

Tags: java, http, servlets, asynchronous, jetty

I'm working on a little proxy server that manages a bunch of tcp-ip connections that run in a selector loop. An external service talks to the proxy server via an http server embedded in the proxy server, and these requests go all the way through to a socket and then return the response from that socket in the response to the original http request.

I have concurrent requests (with a unique request id) coming in on the http server, the actual messages in these requests get stuck on queue and passed along to a bunch of socket connections (a certain socket will correspond to a message), and then the response gets dumped into a hash. The http request checks the hash periodically until it sees a response with the proper request id, or it times out. Here's an awesome system diagram if that makes no sense.

[image: Awesome system diagram]

I'm totally new to using Java for http anything, so I figured I'd use Jetty and set up a simple request handler a la the Hello World example. Using a thread.sleep prevents concurrent requests, and continuations as far as I can tell requires events firing. I'd prefer the requests to check the hash once in a while as opposed to firing a connection event each time a socket puts a response in the hash, unless the events would fire by request id or something. That doesn't seem practical if there's a lot of traffic.

Cliffs:

- How do I make a handler (or servlet, if I need to go that far) wait
  for a bit or periodically while it's data becomes available without
  blocking everything else?
- Is there a better way to make the http
  request aware of data it should return as a response?
- Is this design bad, and if so, what's the alternative?

EDIT:

Here's my first stab at the problem. It works fine when the HTTP request points at an id which corresponds to a connected tcp client. If the id doesn't correspond to a connected client, jetty goes bonkers and gets into a loop and throws the following exception over and over. What I'd expect to happen is the request to time out because it cannot find any messages in the collector.

```
Mar 8, 2012 2:39:08 PM APIRequestHandler doPost
INFO: json: {"state": "255", "m": "set", "id": "00:00:00:00:00:06", "rid": "84955228696f11e1aa04c42c033c8bd7", "sid": "XXXXX"}
2012-03-08 14:39:08.526:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:/
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ASYNCSTARTED,initial
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncContinuation.suspend(AsyncContinuation.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncContinuation.suspend(AsyncContinuation.java:959)
    at APIRequestHandler.doPost(APIRequestHandler.java:72)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1065)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:999)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:900)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:954)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:857)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:609)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:599)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:534)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Servlet:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
        throws java.io.IOException
    {
    String rid = req.getParameter("rid");
    String msg = req.getParameter("json");
    String id = req.getParameter("id");

    // Send to tcp-ip channel
    APIMessage m = new APIMessage();
    m.rid = rid;
    m.id = id;
    m.json = msg + "\r\n";
    queue.add(m);
    this.selector.wakeup();

    Continuation cc = ContinuationSupport.getContinuation(req);

    res.setContentType("text/plain");
    res.getWriter().println("Request: "+rid+"\tstart:\t"+new Date());
    res.getWriter().flush();
    int elapsed = 0;
    String responseStr = "";
    boolean timeoutHappened = true;
    while(elapsed<this.timeout) // say 50 millis
    {
        if(collector.containsKey(rid)){
            responseStr = collector.get(rid);
            collector.remove(rid);
            timeoutHappened = false;
            break;
        }
        cc.setTimeout(10); // sleep 10 millis
        cc.suspend();
    }

    if(!timeoutHappened)
    {
        logger.info("--->API http request found response in collector!");
        logger.info("Respose: "+responseStr);
    }
    else // timed out
    {
        logger.info("--->API http request timed out!");
    }

    res.getWriter().println("Request: "+rid+"\tend:\t"+new Date());
    if(cc.isInitial()!=true) {cc.complete();}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by looking at what we have in jetty for proxying already.

http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/jetty-servlets/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/servlets/ProxyServlet.java

If that doesn't address what your trying to do, it will at least get you started.

You can run that servlet embedded easily with a class in the tests of that package:

http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/jetty-servlets/src/test/java/org/eclipse/jetty/servlets/AsyncProxyServer.java

good luck

Comment: Thanks. I don't think I can use the standard events for timeouts and connects in my case, so I resort to a loop. It works properly unless the incoming request doesn't have a tcp client that corresponds to the passed id. I've added my code above- not sure why it should fail.

Comment: your use of continuations is off, you need to have an isInitial() check in there so you don't execution the same logic more then once, take a look at the proxy servlet for an example on how the continuation mechanism should work.

Comment: Is jetty not multi threaded out of the box? The op seems to say that concurrent requests are queued rather than executing asynchronously?

Comment: Jetty is just being used for HTTP portion, the queued data from the requests is being passed to the selector loop which manages the tcp connections.

Comment: Jetty is multi threaded out of the box, the op is using asynchronous support to servlets through the continuations abstraction incorrectly.  Prior to servlet 3.0 continuations are the only way to really have asynchronous servlets in 2.5.

Comment: I used the servlet 3.0 async context stuff and I believe it works properly now. I need to do some additional verification and then I'll post my code.